# Do -While loops: Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Good Day Everyone,

I've been having a problem with this bit of code for a while now. I'm making a little game and the gist of this little code fragment is that I want to purposefully lock the persons into this pop-up box until they answer yes. However I continuously receive the error message saying that 'while expected'. I've been thinking for about a day now but I cannot figure a way out to answer this question, can someone help me please?

Kind Regards,

Zeno

```
 int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Will you fight?",
        "warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

do {
    / other code / 


}

while (choice


    != 0) {
            choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Will you fight?",
            "warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
}

}

while (ehealth > 0) {

    }

}

}
```

Comment: The nesting - and thus the syntax - is wrong. Use an editor with proper auto-indenting (and actually use the feature) to find the mismatch. It pays to be tidy with code.

Comment: Could you fix your indentation? It's very unclear where one block ends and another starts. Especially the `while` parts, which are the ones you ask about. Also, you could remove all the fighting, as that isn't the problematic post. You should only include relevant code. See how to write a [mcve]. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: With proper formatting it's clearly a syntax error. Also `while(ehealth > 0){}` will run forever and never stop. I think you meant it to be `do {/* code */ } while(ehealth > 0);`

Comment: Syntax issue. Please check how do-while loops are used. It should be like: `do{ // something here}while(<condition check here>);`

Comment: Here you have 3 'while' and one 'do' for each 'while' there must be a 'do' as @AadityaGavandalkar mentioned its syntax issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple syntax issue, refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html for formatting.

So it might look more like this:

```
 boolean loopedOnce=false;
do {

      //execute *other* code once
      //and continues to loop through until choice!=0
   if(loopedOnce) getFightingChoice(); //Method for JPane code
    loopedOnce=true;
    } while(choice!=0);
```

And then continue on in your program with

```
 while(ehealth>0) {
  //more code

 }
```